# need explanation on Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am new to hibernate, when looking at a ancriteria example article; it says:

> You have no way to control the SQL query generated by Hibernate, if the generated query is slow, you are very hard to tune the query, and your database administrator may not like it.

But I think Criteria is used to generate the where clause of the generated SQL, and the where clause are just some conditions added one by one and has nothing to do with query's performance, then how to understand the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

First understand the usage of Hibernate Criteria. This is used to fetch the data from the database and the sql is generated by Hibernate itself. Sometimes due to the configuration of eager fetch, hibernate might unnecessarily generate sql with lot of columns and joins which obviously hamper the performance. In this sense, using HQL is better or even SQL if you cant achieve in HQL (which should not be the case)

Answer (score 0):

Criteria is just a way to programmatically generate a query. It eases the way to generate a query instead of leaving the programmer to do that job by concatenating string with the predicates. Also provides compile time error checking, if you are using canonical model metadata, so fields that are referenced actually exist in the entities.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can't do is to force an index usage since there is no way to add this kind of information (force index) to the generated sql.

Also, hibernate will load all columns from all selected tables, something some DBAs don't like.